# Wave functions as $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, operators, wavefunction

This problem emerged when I was going through some QM exercises:

> I've been asked to find the commutator $[A,B]$ where $A,B$ are defined as
>
> $$A\psi(x)=x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\psi(x),$$
>
> $$B\psi(x)=\int^x_{\infty}\psi(x') dx'.$$

So we have $(AB-BA)\psi(x)=x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int^x_{\infty}\psi(x') dx' - \int^x_{\infty}x'\frac{\partial }{\partial x'}\psi(x')dx'$

We can use integration by parts on the second term to get

$[A,B]\psi(x)=x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int^x_{\infty}\psi(x') dx' - x'\psi(x')|^x_{\infty} + \int^x_{\infty}\psi(x') dx'$

Now having peeked at the solutions, I know that this simplifies to

$x\psi(x) -x\psi(x) + \int^x_{\infty}\psi(x') dx'=B\psi(x)$

I don't understand how the first and second terms simplified. I'm guessing that the normalization requirement that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} |\psi(x) |^2dx=1$ implies that $\psi(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, although I'm not sure how. This would give that the middle term $x'\psi(x')|^x_{\infty}=x\psi(x)-\infty\psi(\infty)$. But writing this isn't really proper iirc, and doesn't show why the expression simplifies to $x\psi(x)$. I'd have to show that $x'\psi(x')\rightarrow 0$ as $x'\rightarrow \infty$. But how do I know this is true for any $\psi$?

I have a similar problem for the first term, if $\psi(x)$ integrates to some function $\phi(x)$, then I'd have to show that $\phi(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: [There are $L^2$-functions which do not fall off at infinity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384992/square-integrable-function-that-doesnt-go-to-zero/408442#408442). It is possible the exercise/solution is simply flawed because domain issues have not been considered - it is, for example, not always the case that $x\psi(x)$ is square-integrable if $\psi(x)$ was. You have to specify the domains of $A$ and $B$ to be able to tell whether $x\psi\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the subspace of Schwartz functions $\psi$ of rapid decrease $\mathscr{S}$ such that their primitive $\Psi$ is in $\mathscr{S}$.

Then $A:D\to D$ (easy to see calculating the primitve with integration by parts); $A$ defined on $\mathscr{S}$ and $B:D\to \mathscr{S}$. Hence on $D$ both $AB$ and $BA$ are well-defined, and
$$[A,B]\psi=B\psi\;,\; \forall \psi\in D\; .$$

Comment: This is overkill. In this approach it is enough to take the intersection of the domains of $A$ and $B$ plus the condition that $x\psi(x)\to0$ when $x\to-\infty$, provided that it is not already satisfied by the domains.

Comment: It is not so overkill...it is not sure that $A(D(A)\cap D(B))\subseteq D(A)\cap D(B)$, $B(D(A)\cap D(B))\subseteq D(A)\cap D(B)$ (so it is not sure that you can apply the commutator on the intersection of the domains in a strong sense). I remind you that with $x$ and $-i\nabla$ the CCR are usually defined on $\mathscr{S}$ for the same reason.

Comment: OK but even granted this I have the feeling that D could be smaller than it need be

Comment: It probably is, but good luck in finding a larger suitable domain (not implicitly defined as the domain where the formula holds) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The first term works out by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

**Edit:**
Deleted my point about square integrability.

Comment: The multiplication and differentiation operators are *not* really self-adjoint without further trickery involving rigged Hilbert spaces, see, for example: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069